# Make the top margin of an element always be the same as the computed height of another

Tags: javascript, css

I have a fixed header, meaning that the content gets lost underneath it unless I give it a top margin equal to the height of the header. This is fine until the header changes size (due to the size of the browser window changing).

At the moment I have an eventListener on window resize, which gets the computed height of the header and applys it to the content's style.marginTop. The problem with this is that I need it to occur on page load, not just window resize, and making so many requests for the header's height as I change the size of the browser window seems bad practice.

Anyone got a better idea? Thanks for any help.

Comment: Use `position: sticky`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
headercheck();
window.addEventListener('resize',headercheck);
function headercheck(){

var headerheight=document.getElementById("header").offsetHeight;
//console.log(headerheight);gives height of header
document.getElementById("content").style.top=headerheight+"px";
}
```

```css
#header{background:#676767;
padding:20px;
box-sizing:border-box;
position:fixed;
width:100%;}
#content{
position:relative;

  }
```

```html
<div id="header">
this is the header 
</div>
<div id ="content">
content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content
</div>
```

hope it helps

Comment: @user3669771 does it help you:)

Answer (score 0):

There are three ways to deal with this problem;

1) Keep using the method you are, but on page load / ready trigger the resize event (Keeps your resizing logic in on place).  This isn't a horrible idea mostly because users don't resize their windows that often.

3) Re-work your header so that when content needs to wrap it becomes available as a pop-up/sliding menu. (Best UI recommendation)

2) Force the content of your header to not wrap (white-space:nowrap) and let the user scroll vertically (Not recommended)

I would personally go for #2, mobile/tablet design is best to keep things out of the way until the user needs it.